# Can a jupyter-lab editor tab be run in a distinct browser window or tab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

As I work on multiple screens, I am wondering if there exists a solution to run an editor tab of Jupyter-lab into an independent tab or window of the browser?

If I understood well this could be somehow accomplished by installing a Jupyterhub locally on my machine, but would there be any simpler solution?

Comment: Just realized that the same jupyter lab session can be opened in two different browsers (i.e. Firefox and Chrome) at the same time, but not in two tabs of the same browser software. A work around...

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the window  by the name, drag in to the right segment of your screen and drop.
[image]

Below is the article which has video how it is done

https://towardsdatascience.com/5-extensions-that-will-make-you-switch-to-jupyter-lab-32c6b66ac755